# GCC headers on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, kubuntu, gcc, c

I was wondering, if there was a go to place to look for c headers, and how to get them on Ubuntu, often times a quick Google search gets me the apt-get package. I was wondering if it possible look up any header `*.h` file and get the required package.

In this particular case I am look for mbstring.h

I am not totally sure if this is the appropriate place for this. If so move as needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

Then, after it is installed and you updated the lists:

```
apt-file search mbstring.h
```

And this is the output that it returned to me:

```
mingw-w64: /usr/amd64-mingw32msvc/include/mbstring.h
mingw32-runtime: /usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include/mbstring.h
php-doc: /usr/share/doc/php-doc/html/book.mbstring.html
php-doc: /usr/share/doc/php-doc/html/intro.mbstring.html
php-doc: /usr/share/doc/php-doc/html/mbstring.http.html
php-doc: /usr/share/doc/php-doc/html/ref.mbstring.html
php5-dev: /usr/include/php5/ext/mbstring/mbstring.h
wine1.0-dev: /usr/include/wine/msvcrt/mbstring.h
wine1.2-dev: /usr/include/wine/msvcrt/mbstring.h
wine1.3-dev: /usr/include/wine/msvcrt/mbstring.h
```